# How to add value at list which that list in a list?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i'm setting up a the model that name is "barang". So i create a some list that the type of list is model "barang". And i add list value in that list.

But i have a trouble when i want to add value in one of the list in the list. 
Can you help me please ?

```
List<Barang> barangnya = new List<Barang> {
                new Barang {IdBarang = 1, NamaBarang = "Buku Tulis", HargaBarang = 5000},
                new Barang {IdBarang = 2, NamaBarang = "Buku Apa", HargaBarang = 4000},
                new Barang {IdBarang = 3, NamaBarang = "Pulpen", HargaBarang = 2000}
            };
```

Comment: what do you mean adding a value in one of list in the list? is there a property in `Barang` which is tpye of `List`?

Comment: i mean when i initialize a value like `new Barang {IdBarang = 1, NamaBarang = "Buku Tulis", HargaBarang = 5000}` ,is it will be a list ?

Comment: yes, there is a property in a model `barang`

Comment: it will be an item in your list, that you have added it when initializing.

Comment: ok thank you for you help

Comment: Kindly check my answer, hope it will help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a little unclear, but this is one of the ways to create and add something into the list:

```
 //creating a list
 List<Barang> barangnya = new List<Barang>();

 //adding items to list
 barangnya.Add(new Barang {IdBarang = 1, NamaBarang = "Buku Tulis", HargaBarang = 5000});
```

[EDIT] 
When you insert something into the List, it doesn't become a list. It is just a member of it.

[EDIT n.2]
You can refer to the members like this:

```
//getting the value of the member
var firstBarangInList = barangnya[0];

//changing a member's attribute
barangnya[1].NamaBarang = "New name";

//removing member from list
barangnya.RemoveAt(3);
```

Comment: so can i edit the member or add a value in the list ?

Comment: yes. You can refer to the members multiple ways and change or delete them.

Comment: can you give an example ? i was very confused

Answer (score 1):

Here you are confused between `List<T>` and `item in the List<T>`, Lets clear the confusion first.

> List : Represents a strongly typed list of objects
>
> T : The type of elements in the list i.e *item in the List*

In your case, `List<Barang>` is a list and `Barang` is type of element.

```
List<Barang> barangnya = new List<Barang> ();
```

Above line creates instance of `List<Barang>`, now you can add elements to it, here element will be instance of your `Barang` class.

Here is the code to add new element to your List.

```
barangnya.Add(new Barang() {IdBarang = 10, NamaBarang = "Prasad", HargaBarang = 6299857});
```

[MSDN : List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.8)